# how to stream object to gzipped json?

Tags: json, go, encoding, stream

Currently the way to convert an object to json and gzip it is:

```golang
jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
//gzip json
var body bytes.Buffer
g := gzip.NewWriter(&body)
g.Write(jsonBytes)
g.Close()
```

This results in an intermediate large byte buffer `jsonBytes`, whose only purpose is to be then converted into gzipped buffer.

Is there any way to *stream* the marshalling of the `payload` object so it comes out gzipped in the first place?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder will help https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go `Streaming Encoders and Decoders`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you may use [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) to stream the JSON output, and similarly [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Dencoder) to decode a streamed JSON input. They take any [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) and [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) to write the JSON result to / read from, including [`gzip.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Writer) and [`gzip.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Reader).

For example:

```
var body bytes.Buffer
w := gzip.NewWriter(&body)

enc := json.NewEncoder(w)

payload := map[string]interface{}{
    "one": 1, "two": 2,
}
if err := enc.Encode(payload); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

To verify that it works, this is how we can decode it:

```
r, err := gzip.NewReader(&body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
payload = nil
if err := dec.Decode(&payload); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Decoded:", payload)
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mp0-UKwnLPX)):

```
Decoded: map[one:1 two:2]
```